# C# Sorting a list by X and Y

Tags: c#, list, sorting

I need to sort a list, by X and Y. I read some on other questions to sort X and Y, but I didn't understand the:

```
List<SomeClass>() a;
List<SomeClass> b = a.OrderBy(x => x.x).ThenBy(x => x.y).ToList();
```

I mean, x => x.x gives undeclared variable error.

Question is: How to sort by X and Y in a list, or: What variable to have instead of x => x.x????

edit: right, my list is like this:

```
List<Class1> MapTiles;
```

and in class: int ID, int X, int Y

Thanx.

Comment: `List<SomeClass>() a;` will not compile.  Write `List<SomeClass> a = new List<SomeClass>();`.  Or, identical (but less noisy) code: `var a = new List<SomeClass>();`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

C# is case sensitive. You need

```
// Note the capital letters
List<SomeClass> b = a.OrderBy(item => item.X).ThenBy(item => item.Y).ToList();
```

Comment: I would even encourage you to rewrite it to read as `a.OrderBy(item => item.X).ThenBy(item => item.Y).ToList()`. Write readable code, not short code.

Comment: @Marcus You may want show us the entire code snippet, and the entire text of the error.

Comment: @dlev: Pure speculation, but it's possible some people would read OrderBy(x => x.x) and not understand that it's creating a delegate around that has a named variable "x" and grabbing the property named "x" from the variable "x". I don't know what Marcus is thinking or what he's doing, but that could be the case here.

Comment: @Mike I agree, it's very confusing code. And apparently still broken.

Comment: @Marcus You have a `<` after `OrderBy` when you need a `(`.

Comment: Syntax error right here: `List<Class1> b = MapTiles.OrderBy<x => x.X).ThenBy(x => x.Y).ToList();` You're doing `MapTiles.OrderBy<x => x.X)`. This should be `MapTiles.OrderBy(x => x.X)`. You made a typo is all. (Ninja'd by 16 seconds!). @Marcus: This is sorting all the items in the list, but what you're doing is essentially creating a delegate. I'll add answer to explain what's going on but dlev's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

***dlev's answer is the correct one to this question, the following is just an extended explanation of a concept that Marcus may have not understood fully***

Just to clarify some point that was brought up in the comments, what's happening is you're actually passing in a delegate to do the sorting.

The following snippet

```
List<Item> b = a.OrderBy(item => item.X);
```

Is like creating a static compare function that sorts by comparing the field (or property) `X` of an object of type `Item` and passing that compare function into a sort function, as you might do in C++.

The OrderBy(...) is just a very short and convenient way of accomplishing this.